# Login with google with create-react-native-app and firebase (using exponent)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, create-react-native-app

By this code.

```
googleAuthenticate = (token) => {
const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const credential = provider.credential(token)
return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential) }


gglogin = async () => {
const LogInResult = await Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: '<my-androidClientId>',
      iosClientId: '<my-IOSClientId>',
      scopes: ['profile', 'email']
});

if(LogInResult.type === 'success'){
  Alert.alert(
        'Logged in!',
        `Hi ${user.name}!`,
      );
  this.googleAuthenticate(LogInResult.accessToken)
}
```

}

It's can get username alert but can't send token to firebase by getting this error.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
  TypeError: this.addScope is not a function. (In 
 'this.addScope("profile")', 'this.addScope' is undefined)`
```

Please what is wrong

Comment: can you share your app.json or a github repo link?

Comment: I am having trouble with google signin in an expo standalone android app, not able to get the username or profile.  I just wanted to check your app.json file to see if I have made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice 2 issues, credential is a static method, and the first parameter is an id token and the second an access token (you are passing an access token it seems):

```
const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your scopes to provider as below:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

Please check again this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider

You need to change your code as below :

```
googleAuthenticate = (token) => {
const provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
const credential = provider.credential(token)
return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential) }
```

Comment: Thank you bro. But still not work with new error
"the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application"
think it's because I don't know how to setup on firebase.

Comment: Create an application on your Firebase account and use your JSON file, you can download it after you create an application on your account.